# Rcpp containers do not release memory

Tags: rcpp

Rcpp containers seem not to release memory after it goes out of function scope:

```
# include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;


double f(int siz)
{
  IntegerVector a = Rcpp::sample(siz, siz);
  return std::accumulate(a.begin(), a.end(), 0.0);
}


// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector test(int siz)
{
  NumericVector rst(siz);
  for(int i = 0; i < siz; ++i)
  {
    rst[i] = f(siz);
  }
  return rst;
}


/***R
rst = test(1000000)
*/
```

The above program soon fills out my 32GB memory. How to release memory allocated for the `Rcpp::IntegerVector` in `f()` ?

Thank you

Note: Use `IntegerVector a = Language("sample", siz, siz).eval()` instead. Space for `a` will be released out of the function immediately.

Note2: by reading the source code of `Rcpp`, the best solution is to program a customized `sample()`. The central component of `Rcpp::sample()` is `unif_rand()`. Integrate `unif_rand()` in the modern version of Fisher–Yates Shuffle. Problem solved.

Comment: At the end of `f()`, and under C++ semantics, `a` is gone. BUT it is an Rcpp object meaning it is in R's memory pool _by design_ so that we can do what `test()` does -- return objects.  If you trigger sufficient `gc()` from R, you will get `a`'s memory back but this is not deterministic _as it is meant to work for an interpreted language_.  If you want `std::vector<>` behaviour, use `std::vector<>`.